# Problems deploying cloud functions on GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have been working on several personal projects using cloud functions and never had any issues deploying. Recently I notice the deployment takes a long time and ends time exceeding a timeout. The build is successful, but for some reason the creation of the service just hangs indefinitely. The cloud functions I am trying to deploy were all perfectly functioning one week ago and oddly enough I don't have any quotas limit exceeded per project and region.

Just to give a better idea the process gets stuck at this step "[Service] Creating Cloud Run service":

⠶ Deploying function...
✓ [Build] Logs are available at ...
⠶ [Service] Creating Cloud Run service...
. [ArtifactRegistry]
. [Healthcheck]
. [Triggercheck]

Does anyone know the reason, or has been facing similar issues in the last week?

I simply tried to deploy the 6 cloud functions I have always been deploying but it looks like I can just deploy a few, because from the third one on the service starts hanging until it hits a hard timeout. I was expecting all 6 cloud functions get deployed normally.
I have even tried to change the region (from europe-west2 to 3)

This is the message I find in the GCP console

"Cloud Run service [...] for the function was not found. The function will not work correctly. Please redeploy."

Comment: Are you using container image from container registry/Artifact registry ?

Comment: How do you deploy your Cloud Functions (your command/API call/Terraform or whatever)? Do you use gen2 functions? What's your code language?